# Call a class function with button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to use a class in a button-click event.

**File: Character.cs**

```
public class Character
{
    public Character(string name, int health, int weight, int gold, Inventory inventory)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Health = health;
        this.Weight = weight;
        this.Gold = gold;
        this.Inventory = inventory;
    }

    public string Name;
    public int Health;
    public int Gold;
    public int Weight;
    public Inventory Inventory;
}
```

I create a character in the **Form1.cs File**.

```
Character Adventurer = new Character("Geralt von Riva", 100, 50, 5, new Inventory(new Weapon(1, "Needle", 5, 5, 15, 0), new Armor(2, "Jerkin", 3, 11, 5), new Potion(3, "Little Healhy", 2, 0, 20)));
```

This works fine. Now, i'd like to add a button (named button1 here) in the form. So I drag&dropped a button from the toolbox into the form designer. After a little doubleclick, visual studio added this lines of code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here i would like to do something like this:
        Adventurer.Inventory.WeaponList.Add(new Weapon(...));
    }
```

The Problem is, i cannot use Adventurer outside of the public Form1() class of the Form1.cs File. How do I get this Adventurer "public"? I'm kinda new to this, so please be kind.

Comment: simply make adventurer public

Comment: Where do you declare your Adventurer? In a method or in the class?

Comment: Comment Nr.1 solved the problem. No idea why didn't I come up with this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to be able to access the instance you should declare the variable in global scope like

```
public Form1 : Form
{
  private Character Adventurer = null;
  public Form1()
  {
      Adventurer = new Character(.....); 
  }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here i would like to do something like this:
        Adventurer.Inventory.WeaponList.Add(new Weapon(...));
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend using properties, not public fields.

Comment: @Mafii, that's true but if this is what OP missing then it could be a `private` field as well... see edit in answer.